# how can position element like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the link below in the bottom of page we see some box that aligned with the javascript or jquery,and they are not in the same row. this can't be done with css.
and when the page width change they realigned with smomth animation.
any body know how to do that? is there any video to teach this technic?
http://esam.ir/itemView.aspx/562755/%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B4-%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C.htm

thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy library called Masonry, have a look at that, they have some decent documentation and it works exactly like you want it. But going into the details of how its done is beyond the scope of a stack overflow post.

http://masonry.desandro.com